# Spring Batch tasklet configuration

Tags: spring, spring-batch

My batch Job takes input of 15 different files and the first step in my job is a Validate Step which will validate the header and total no of records, next step is the chunk based tasklet.

Now in validation, I have different if-else cases in my tasklet to handle different validations for the files and the cases are based on the file name and extension which are been passed as Job parameters. In this case I need to know whether the tasklet reference for my validation step can be decided upon runtime. i.e I'll have bean references for validators for 15 files and based upon the file extension in the job parameters my tasklet ref should be taken at runtime.

```
    <batch:job id="downloadFile">

    <batch:step id="validator" >
        <batch:tasklet ref="InteropValidator"/>
            <batch:next on="FAILED" to="AckStep"/>
            <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="loadFiles"/>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="loadFiles" next="AckStep">
        <partition step="slave" partitioner="partitionerFactory">
            <handler grid-size="1" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </partition>
    </batch:step>

        <batch:step id="AckStep" >
            <batch:tasklet ref="Acksteptasklet"/>
            <batch:fail on="FAILED"/>
    </batch:step>

</batch:job>
```

In InteropValidator java, I have implemented the tasklet interface and written code snippet as below:

```
    if("ICTX".equals(FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename)))
{
if(fileValidated && detailValid && agencyValid )
{
cc.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("STATUSCODE","01");
sc.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.COMPLETED);
}
}
if("SML".equals(FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename)))
{
    //Validations for SML File
}
```

Comment: You can have a delegate tasklet and have a map which is to map file extenstion with the 'real bean validation'. How far you have tried so far?

Comment: @NghiaDo: Added the batch context, i have written validation for one of the files and my thought was to add all the file validation conditions as if else cases as shown above, in the above case , I have only 2 but in real there will be more than 15 if - else cases which makes my code messy. Thanks for help. Can you please provide reference link or snippet on how to use a delegate tasklet with respect to the above scenario. Thanks a lot for your help though.